# SQL Server 2008 R2 dynamically update formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need your help in the following situation if is possible:
I use Sql Server 2008 R2 and I have this table:

```
create table tblContracts 
([ContractID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PlotNumber] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[TotalArea] [numeric](12, 0) NULL,
[NotaryCosts] [numeric](12, 2) NULL,
[LandTax] [numeric](12, 2) NULL,
[OtherTaxes] [numeric](12, 2) NULL)
```

In this table I could have several records with the same `ContractID` but with different `PlotNumber`.
I want to dinamically split the costs for each `PlotNumber` depending on `TotalArea` where `ContractID` is the same.

For e.g. if I have next records:

```
1. ContractID=1,PlotNumber=1,TotalArea=100,NotaryCosts=300,LandTax=10,OtherTaxes=0 and
2. ContractID=1,PlotNumber=2,TotalArea=200,NotaryCosts=?,LandTax=20,OtherTaxes=0
```

The formula for `NotaryCosts` should update itself dynamically according to the next formula:

`NotaryCosts`(for each `PlotNumber`)=sum(`NotaryCosts` with the same `ContractID`)/sum(`TotalArea` with the same `ContractID`)*`TotalArea`(for the specific `PlotNumber`)

It is possible to do this somehow?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: computed data should not be stored in the database, instead, you could create a view that calculate this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much agree with Thomas, I think the table design needs some work as well as how data is being entered into the system.  At any rate here is a query that could be used as view to give you the calculated total you are look for or could be used in an Update statement.  To do this automatically this logic would need to be placed in a trigger

```
select
tc.ContractID
,tc.PlotNumber
,tc.TotalArea 
,tc.TotalArea *tcTotals.Cost_Per_Area as [Notary_Cost]
,tc.LandTax
,tc.OtherTaxes 
from
tblContracts  tc
inner join
(
select 
ContractID
,SUM(notaryCosts) as [sum_NotaryCost]
,SUM(TotalArea) as [sum_TotalArea]
,SUM(notaryCosts)/SUM(TotalArea) as [Cost_Per_Area]
from 
tblContracts
group by
ContractID
) tcTotals
on
tc.ContractID =tcTotals.ContractID
```